# How print the fibonacci nodes of a linked list? For example we print 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 5th, 8th etc. nodes in a linked list

Tags: c, structure

I am trying to find out the most efficient way of doing this. I have the following code below for printing fibonacci series for first ten elements (using memoization)

```
int main()
{
    int arrayWithFibIndices[100] = {0}; //Explanation for this array comes later
    int series[10] = {0}; //array to store the fibonacci values for last two iterations
    series[0] = 1; //hard coding the first two elements of the fib series
    series[1] = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {   
        if (series[i] != 0)
        {   
            printf ("series[%d]=%d.\n", i, series[i]);
        }   
        else 
        {   
            series[i] = series[i - 1] + series[i - 2]; 
            printf ("series[%d]=%d.\n", i, series[i]);
        }
        arrayWithFibIndices[series[i]] = 1;
    }   
}
```

I also have the following logic to print the linked list iteratively.

```
void printLL(struct node *temp)
{
    int i  = 0;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {   
        if (arrayWithFibIndices[i] != 0) //reason explained later below
        {
            printf("data:%d ", temp->data);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        i++;
    }   
    printf("\n");
}
```

I am trying to figure out what would be the most efficient way of doing this? First thing that comes to my mind is create a new array arrayWithFibIndices[] and initialize all the elements of the array to 0. Whenever we come across a fibonacci value, we will then populate that index in arrayWithFibIndices[] with 1. We can later check for each index of arrayWithFibIndices[] before printing the value of the linked list.

Second thought that occurred to me was to create a queue. I will Enqueue all the Fibonacci elements and when it comes to printing Linked List, I will dequeue on successful match (match being that the queue element matches with the i'th element of the linked list.

Do you guys have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your suggested solution in the description will work. However, you don't need to do a pass to get a list of all Fibanocci numbers. You can just keep track of the previous number and use to offset your current node in the list.

Here is a simple example demonstrating how it would work.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

void create_linked_list(struct node **root_ptr, int count) {
    struct node **curr_ptr = root_ptr;
    struct node *curr = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        *curr_ptr = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node *));
        curr = *curr_ptr;
        curr->data = i + 1;
        curr->next = NULL;
        curr_ptr = &(curr->next);
    }
}

void print_linked_list(struct node *root) {
    for(struct node *curr = root; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next) {
        printf("%d\n", curr->data);
    }
}

void print_linked_list_fib(struct node *root) {
    struct node *curr = root;

    // Print the root node twice because of 1,1
    // 1
    printf("%d\n", curr->data);
    int old_val = 1;

    // 1
    printf("%d\n", curr->data);
    int curr_val = 1;

    int offset = old_val;

    while (true) {
        // Keep moving until the next fibonacci node.
        for (int i = 0; i < offset; i++) {
            if (curr == NULL) return;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        if (curr == NULL) return;
        printf("%d\n", curr->data);
        old_val = curr_val;
        curr_val = curr_val + offset;
        offset = old_val;
    }

}

int main() {
    struct node *root = NULL;
    const int count = 20;
    create_linked_list(&root, count);

    printf("\n\nList of all nodes\n");
    print_linked_list(root);

    printf("\n\nList of fibonacci nodes\n");
    print_linked_list_fib(root);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the sample output

```
List of all nodes
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20


List of fibonacci nodes
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
```

*EDIT:* An alternative way to write the print function for fibonacci nodes. 
This flattens the two loops from the previous implementation into a single loop.

```
void print_linked_list_fib_loop(struct node *root) {
    struct node *curr = root;

    // Print the root node twice because of 1,1
    // 1
    printf("%d\n", curr->data);
    int old_val = 1;

    // 1
    printf("%d\n", curr->data);
    int curr_val = 1;

    int i = 0;
    curr = curr->next;
    for(struct node *curr = root; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next) {
        if (i == old_val) {
            old_val = curr_val;
            curr_val = curr_val + i;
            i = 0;
            printf("%d\n", curr->data);
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are also designing and building the list, during building you could copy addresses of fibonacci nodes into a separate array of `struct node*`. For managing any reordering of nodes, you would store list position in each node (and change it if, for example, a node is added or deleted). This is overhead if the list will be manipulated often, but printing the fibonacci nodes becomes very efficient: just step through your array of pointers, without traversing the linked list at all.